# Scatterplot with repeat values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to produce scatterplots.

For some of the points, I have lots of rows in my data set with the exact same x and y values.

Is there any way to have this situation reflected in the scatter-plot?

Comment: Would a base graphics answer be helpful?

Comment: Try to set `alpha = 0.1` inside `geom_point()`

Comment: `geom_jitter()` is another nice way to show repeated values.

Answer (score 0):

[geom_count()](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_count.html) reflects the number of observations at each position in the size of the dot.